# Using inline-block vs inline, both don't seem to work to what I'm expecting

Tags: html, css

```css
*, html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: -apple-system, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; background: #ffe6eb; color: #4E2B99;}
.container { margin: 0px auto; max-width: 1000px; text-align: center; }
.header img { width: 5em; }

/* item */
.item { max-width: 500px; display: inline-block; }
.item .byf { font-style: italic; }
.item .byf-avatar { max-width: 1em; border-radius: 1em; }
.item .content { margin-top: 10px; min-height: 200px; background-color: white; border-radius: 5px; }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Friends of Friends - Peach</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" class="container">
      <!-- Begin Header -->
      <div id="header" class="header">
        <img src="http://peach.cool/images/icon-peach-header-big@2x.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <!-- End Header-->

      <!-- Begin Content -->
      <div id="content" class="content">
        <div id="items" class="items">

          <!-- Begin Item -->
          <div id="item-1" class="item">
            <span class="byf">Because you follow <img src="https://scontent.fcmh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/38600406_695730037430614_8379042433521942528_o.jpg?_nc_cat=103&oh=e3b71b3b819c1bd035c98057e5b7a69a&oe=5C4FEC80" alt="avatar-1" class="byf-avatar" /> <strong>Name</strong>... </span>
            <div id="content" class="content">
              <div class="content-list">
                <div class="content-list-item">
                  <span class="cli-name">Name</span> @<span class="cli-handle"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Item -->

          <!-- Begin Item -->
          <div id="item-1" class="item">
            <span class="byf">Because you follow <img src="image" alt="avatar-1" class="byf-avatar" /> <strong>Name</strong>... </span>
            <div id="content" class="content">
              <div class="content-list">
                <div class="content-list-item">
                  <span class="cli-name">Name</span> @<span class="cli-handle"></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Item -->

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Content -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56jgh7Lx/

I have various items (`class="item"`) that I am trying to create a grid for. Each item should have a maximum width of 500 and the container they are within has a variable width of 1000px. When I use display: inline on the item class, it changes the width of all items to 1000px, obviously not what I'm looking for. If I use display: inline-block, it changes the width to 200-something pixels.

I am a little confused why this is happening, especially since my width is set to a max of 500px. I am new to CSS and would love to learn and understand more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the `max-width`, not the `display`. Both `inline-block` and `inline` were doing what they were supposed to do. On inline elements, `width`s applied in CSS don't apply. On `inline-block`, they do.

However, CSS `max-width` only takes effect if the content is wider than the `max-width`. Currently, your content is not more than 500px wide. You need to set a `width` property for `max-width` to take effect, like this.

```
.item{
    max-width:500px;
    width: 100%;
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline-block;` will take height, width and will display next to each other while `display:inline` doesn't take height and width but will display to each other. for you `max-width:500px` its working because you're content is just `200px` wide, if you widen your contents you will get a scrolling effect or your content will go outside the container if its more than 500px.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal scenrio, inline container cannot hold block level elements. 
In your case class="item" you are trying to have inline which is holding child of class="content" which is block element and as expected you inline container width will be of the block child element.